# avoid extra divs in jquery loadTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, template-engine, jquery-templates

i am experimenting with loadTemplate plugin of jquery and when I try to compose a table, extra divs generates in the template:

my html:

```
<table class="pure-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>body</th>
            </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="templateContainer">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

my template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template" >
    <tr>
        <td data-content="title"></td>
        <td data-content="body"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

my code:

```
function carga() {

    //se puede apuntar a dentro de la aplicacion
    var client = new $.RestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/');

    client.add("posts");
    //jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post/1
    client.posts.read('1').done(
            function (data) {

                //add properties in first object of next objects
                informacion.push(data);
                //esta dentro porque es asincrono
                $("#templateContainer").loadTemplate($("#template"), informacion);
            });
}
```

the result:

```
<table class="pure-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>body</th>
            </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody id="templateContainer">
<div>
<div>
<tr>
            <td>suntit</td>
            <td>quia et</td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i don't understand why the div of the internal table is created.

any idea?

Comment: The jquery-template tag is for jquery templates not for loadTemplate. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-templates/info